# APInf: Not able to add API using private IP address

Tags: fiware

I am not able to publish API on APInf(https://github.com/apinf/platform) with bare private IP address while the same API i am able to publish on API-Umbrella.
I have used latest version of APInf and API-Umbrella and followed the steps given at below URl for installation:
[Installation Steps](https://github.com/apinf/platform/blob/develop/INSTALL.md#with-docker-compose)

I'd like to confirm that if we want to use APInf with our private certificates then what is the procedure to install?

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue open about that (and it got promptly hijacked by other stuff):
https://github.com/apinf/platform/issues/3718

there is a workaround:  ipv4 IPs you can do like this:

http://12.33.56.78

and should be fine. There is a regex protecting that field. We are going to do something about this when we have the time. Sorry for the inconvenience